# Outlook Interop "The RPC server is unavailable" when email is opened

Tags: .net, outlook, office-interop

Using Outlook Interop, I have created a small app to connect to my Outlook inbox and collect 30 emails, then display them in a grid. When you double click on an email in the grid, it will open the email in Outlook.

In the app:
- Open an email, minimise it. Then open another, it will open fine.
- Open an email, close it. Then open another, you will get a 'The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT:
   0x800706BA)' error.

I noticed that when this happens, the Outlook icon in the system tray disappears.

I have tried creating a new instance of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application and namespace and adding the registry setting found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rgregg/archive/2008/10/27/application-shutdown-changes-in-outlook-2007-service-pack-2-beta.aspx

I am running Office 2010.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1
    Private m_outlookApplication As Application                                                         'Outlook
    Private m_nameSpace As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace                                   'Outlook's namespace
    Private WithEvents m_inboxItems As Items                                                            'All Outlook inbox items
    Private WithEvents m_calendarItems As Items                                                         'All Outlook calendar items
    Private m_outlookInstalled As Boolean = False                                                       'indicates whether Outlook is installed on computer
    Private m_emails As New List(Of OutlookInboxEmail)                                                  'used to store inbox e-mail messages for grid view control
    Private m_inboxFolder As MAPIFolder                                                                 'Outlook inbox folder
    Private m_calendarFolder As MAPIFolder                                                              'Outlook calendar
    Private m_explorer As Explorer                                                                      'Outlook window explorer
    Private m_name As String = String.Empty                                                             'the name user who is connected
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        connectToOutlook()

        loadInbox()
    End Sub
    Private Sub connectToOutlook()
        m_outlookApplication = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
        m_nameSpace = m_outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        m_nameSpace.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, False, True)
        Dim connectionMode = m_nameSpace.ExchangeConnectionMode
    End Sub
    Private Sub loadInbox()
        Try

            'get inbox folder
            m_inboxFolder = m_nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
            'get inbox messages
            m_inboxItems = m_inboxFolder.Items
            m_emails.Clear()
            'display recent messages first
            m_inboxItems.Sort("ReceivedTime", True)

            Dim numberOfEmailsToLoad As Integer = 30
            'set displayed values for each message
            For Each currentItem As Object In m_inboxItems
                Dim emailItem = TryCast(currentItem, MailItem)
                If Not emailItem Is Nothing Then
                    'check whether its e-mail
                    If emailItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
                        'set email
                        Dim inboxEmail As New OutlookInboxEmail
                        inboxEmail.SenderName = emailItem.SenderName
                        inboxEmail.Subject = emailItem.Subject
                        inboxEmail.ReceivedTime = emailItem.ReceivedTime.ToString("dd MMMM HH:mm")
                        inboxEmail.Body = emailItem.Body
                        inboxEmail.Unread = emailItem.UnRead
                        inboxEmail.Email = emailItem
                        m_emails.Add(inboxEmail)
                        numberOfEmailsToLoad = numberOfEmailsToLoad - 1
                        If numberOfEmailsToLoad <= 0 Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            If m_explorer Is Nothing Then
                Try
                    m_explorer = m_outlookApplication.ActiveExplorer
                Catch ex As System.Exception

                End Try
            End If

            If GridControl1.DataSource Is Nothing Then
                GridControl1.DataSource = Nothing
                GridControl1.DataSource = m_emails
            End If
            GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()
        Catch exception As System.Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Opens email in Outlook
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub openEmail()
        If Not GridView1.GetFocusedDataSourceRowIndex < 0 Then
            Dim selectedEmail = TryCast(m_emails(GridView1.GetFocusedDataSourceRowIndex), OutlookInboxEmail)
            If Not selectedEmail Is Nothing Then
                Try

                    If Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() = 0 Then

                    End If

                    selectedEmail.Email.Display()
                    selectedEmail.Unread = False
                    selectedEmail.EmailImage = My.Resources.Read_16
                Catch exception As COMException

                End Try
                GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub GridControlCalendar_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridControl1.DoubleClick
        openEmail()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you see the taskbar icon disappear then the exception is the expected outcome.  No hint whatsoever why it decided to quit.  Look in the Windows application log for breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several hours of investigation, when a message is closed it closes Outlook with it.

The solution was to check before interacting with Outlook, that Outlook was open. Having a timer running every 2 minutes that ran the same check ensured that the Outlook Inbox view I created was only ever 2 minutes out of date if Outlook closed.

```
Private Sub openEmail()
        If Not GridViewInbox.GetFocusedDataSourceRowIndex < 0 Then
            Dim selectedEmail = TryCast(m_emails(GridViewInbox.GetFocusedDataSourceRowIndex), OutlookInboxEmail)
            If Not selectedEmail Is Nothing Then
                Try
                    If Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() = 0 Then
                        'if outlook is not open.. open it
                        m_selectedEmail = selectedEmail
                        reconnectOutlook()
                    Else
                        'as outlook is open, open the email
                        selectedEmail.Email.Display()
                        selectedEmail.Unread = False
                        selectedEmail.EmailImage = ImageLibrary.My.Resources.Read_16
                        GridControlInbox.RefreshDataSource()
                        m_selectedEmail = Nothing
                    End If
                Catch exception As COMException
                    EventLog.write(exception)
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not open email. Please start Outlook and try again.", "Opening Email", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End Try
                GridControlInbox.RefreshDataSource()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The reconnection code...

```
Private Sub connectToOutlook()
    Try
        m_outlookApplication = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
        m_nameSpace = m_outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        'start Outlook
        Dim connectionMode = m_nameSpace.ExchangeConnectionMode
        m_nameSpace.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, False, True)
        'get the name of user
        m_name = m_outlookApplication.Session.CurrentUser.Name
        m_outlookInstalled = True
    Catch exception As System.Exception
        If Not exception.Message.IndexOf("Class not registered") = -1 Then
            'Outlook is not installed
            m_outlookInstalled = False
            EventLog.write(exception)
        Else
            EventLog.write(exception)
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```